# Add multiple rows to a single php while loop variable

Tags: php

I currently have this code that's working just fine:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($popupResult)) {
  $popupQuote     = $row['quoteNumber'];
  $popupExp       = $row['quoteCustomer'];
  $popupCost      = $row['quoteExpirationDate'];
  }
```

My only issue is that the data in my table that contains what I want in $popupQuote COULD have `quoteNumber` populated, or it could have `debitNumber` populated - but it will never have both.  I need this basically:

```
  $popupQuote     = $row['quoteNumber'] or $row['debitNumber']
```

If I use `$popupQuote     = $row['quoteNumber'];`, I get 6 results.  If I use `$popupQuote     = $row['debitNumber'];` I can 4 results.  I want the output to display all 10 results in a single variable.

Comment: Thanks for the edit... darn copy & paste :)

Answer (score 3):

If you guarantee that one of the two fields will always be populated, and never will there be a record with both or neither, then:

```
$poupQuote = !empty($row['quoteNumber']) ? $row['quoteNumber'] : $row['debitNumber'];
```

e.g. check if quotenumber has a value. if it does, use that value, otherwise use the debitnumber. Of course, you'll probably want some better checking, since `empty()` will bite you in the rump if quotenumber can be `0` - empty(0) is true.

Comment: There needs to be a closing bracket though on ['quoteNumber']

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional expression:

```
$popupQuote = $row['quoteNumber'] ? $row['quoteNumber'] : $row['debitNumber'];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [Ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

And test if there is a value

```
$popupQuote = ($row['quoteNumber'] != "") ? $row['quoteNumber'] : $row['debitNumber'];
```

Comment: isset wouldn't work. the field will always be present in the result row... it just might not have a value.

Comment: Oh, I see you have something similar.